# Edit XML Document from WebService Method

Tags: c#, xml, web-services

I've got a Web Service that uses an XML document and I'm trying to add a function that adds a new node to the XML document. It runs fine and doesn't break, but the save function doesn't seem to work? Here's the code;

```
[WebMethod]
public void AddNodeTEST()
{
    XmlDocument xmlUpdateCfg = new XmlDocument();

    try
    {
        xmlUpdateCfg.Load(Context.Request.MapPath("Updates.xml"));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }

    XmlNode updateInfo = xmlUpdateCfg.SelectSingleNode("updateinfo");

    /* Create the downloadmodule node */
    XmlNode newDownloadModule = xmlUpdateCfg.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "downloadmodule", null);
    newDownloadModule.InnerText = "download/test.CAB";
    XmlAttribute downloadModuleName = xmlUpdateCfg.CreateAttribute("name");
    downloadModuleName.Value = "Test";
    newDownloadModule.Attributes.Append(downloadModuleName);

    /* Create the version node */
    XmlNode newVersion = xmlUpdateCfg.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "version", null);
    XmlAttribute versionMaj = xmlUpdateCfg.CreateAttribute("maj");
    versionMaj.Value = "1";
    XmlAttribute versionMin = xmlUpdateCfg.CreateAttribute("min");
    versionMin.Value = "2";
    XmlAttribute versionBld = xmlUpdateCfg.CreateAttribute("bld");
    versionBld.Value = "3";
    XmlAttribute versionRev = xmlUpdateCfg.CreateAttribute("rev");
    versionRev.Value = "4";
    newVersion.Attributes.Append(versionMaj);
    newVersion.Attributes.Append(versionMin);
    newVersion.Attributes.Append(versionBld);
    newVersion.Attributes.Append(versionRev);

    /* Add the newVersion node to the newDownloadModule node */
    newDownloadModule.AppendChild(newVersion);

    /* Add the newDownloadModule to the updateinfo Node*/
    updateInfo.AppendChild(newDownloadModule);

    xmlUpdateCfg.Save("Updates.xml");
}
```

and here is the XML structure;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<updateinfo>
  <downloadmodule name="test">
    <version maj="1" min="0" bld="4" rev="0"/>
    Download/cabfile.CAB
  </downloadmodule>
</updateinfo>
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!.

Comment: xmlUpdateCfg.Save(Context.Request.MapPath("Updates.xml"));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't you be calling xmlUpdateCfg.Save(Context.Request.MapPath("Updates.xml")) so that it saves it to the same location it read it from?

Comment: I tried too but it says I had to wait 6 minutes or so!